# Jest, TypeORM, and typescript failing to run tests

Tags: typescript, jestjs, typeorm, ts-jest

I am using TS with TypeORM, mysql and jest to build a schema factory, however, my test suites are failing to run since they are throwing a syntax error regarding the import statement. The main part I am getting confused around is the fact the project builds and into the `dist/` folder, however, running  a test suite like below throws an error. Any help would be greatly appreciated as I am not too what the issue is.

**Error Being Thrown**

```
/Users/xxxx/Work/schemasproject/src/entity/HistoricalRental.ts:1
import { Entity } from 'typeorm';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:353:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1039:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1073:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1138:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:989:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:829:14)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1013:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:93:18)
    at /Users/xxxx/Work/schemasproject/node_modules/typeorm/util/DirectoryExportedClassesLoader.js:42:39
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
```

**index.test.ts**

```
describe('Historical Sales Tests', () => {
  beforeAll(async () => {
    console.log('before');
  });

  describe('Creation', () => {
    it('Should create the row', async () => {
      console.log('here');
    });
  });
});
```

**/src/entity/HistoricalRental.ts - where Property is a basic class with a primary key and some columns**

```
import { Entity } from 'typeorm';
import { Property } from '../abstract/Property';

@Entity()
export class HistoricalRental extends Property {}
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "schemas",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "src/index.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "rm -rf dist && tsc",
    "lint": "eslint './src/**/*.{ts,tsx}'",
    "postpublish": "git clean -fd",
    "prepublishOnly": "npm run build && cp -r ./dist/* . && rm -rf ./dist",
    "pretest": "npm run lint",
    "test": "jest --config=jest.config.js -i --forceExit",
    "testOnly": "jest --config=jest.config.js -i --forceExit"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.24",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.28.5",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.28.5",
    "eslint": "^7.31.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "^14.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.23.4",
    "jest": "^27.0.6",
    "ts-jest": "^27.0.4",
    "typescript": "^4.3.5"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "mysql": "^2.18.1",
    "typeorm": "^0.2.34"
  }
}
```

**jest.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  testEnvironment: 'node',
  roots: ['<rootDir>/src'],
  globalSetup: './src/__tests__/environment/globalSetup.ts',
  globalTeardown: './src/__tests__/environment/globalTeardown.ts',
  clearMocks: true,
  maxWorkers: 1,
  preset: 'ts-jest',
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.(ts|tsx)?$': 'ts-jest',
  },
  testRegex: '(\\.|/)(test|spec)\\.ts?$',
  moduleFileExtensions: ['ts', 'tsx', 'js', 'jsx', 'json', 'node'],
  collectCoverage: true,
  coverageReporters: ['text'],
};
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "ES6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "strictFunctionTypes": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "emitDeclarationOnly": true
  },
  "exclude": ["./src/__tests__", "./src/__mocks__", "./src/**/*.spec.ts", "./dist/"]
}
```

**ormconfig.js**

```
const { join } = require('path');

module.exports = {
  type: 'mysql',
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 3306,
  username: 'test',
  password: 'test',
  database: 'test',
  synchronize: true,
  logging: false,
  entities: [join(__dirname, './**/*.entity{.ts,.js}')],
  migrations: [
    'src/migration/**/*.ts',
  ],
  subscribers: [
    'src/subscriber/**/*.ts',
  ],
  cli: {
    entitiesDir: 'src/entity',
    migrationsDir: 'src/migration',
    subscribersDir: 'src/subscriber',
  },
};
```